# linux redhat + how to resolve the issue about Invalid response packet from host

Tags: linux, redhat, syslog, avahi, dmesg

we have thousand of the following message in **/var/log/messages**

we also have strange issue that machine restart each of couple dayes

what need to do in order to avoid these messages?

```
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.62.110.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.42.214.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.56.252.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.60.181.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.56.229.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.61.249.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.60.171.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.44.218.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.60.164.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.61.247.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.58.59.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.62.106.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.61.244.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.61.38.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.58.58.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.54.180.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.60.163.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.61.246.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.54.182.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.61.46.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.47.248.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.7.166.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.60.94.
Apr 25 00:08:31 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.46.108.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.58.56.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.34.247.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.60.180.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.36.86.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.27.116.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.62.111.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.45.202.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.48.29.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.48.32.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.61.135.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.47.244.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.58.63.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.48.52.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.62.207.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.58.159.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.56.199.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.42.241.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.60.61.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.35.160.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.22.128.
Apr 25 00:08:32 app_linux02 avahi-daemon[953]: Invalid response packet from host 91.61.56.231.
```

Comment: Do you need avahi? If not, just disable it...

Comment: what the propose of avahi ? for what we need it ?

Comment: Do you really expect me to google this for you? In most servers, you shouldn't need zeroconf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
systemctl disable --now avahi-daemon
```

and read your OS documentation...

(`--now` will also stop the running service, otherwise you would have to also use `systemctl stop avahi-daemon`).

Answer (score 0):

we can stop the service and then turn it off at boot using these two commands:

```
service avahi-daemon stop 
chkconfig avahi-daemon off
```

Comment: FYI: My variant is the preferred version on EL7, `service` and `chkconfig` are just compability layers to systemctl.

Comment: another question please , do you think when this service is running , then in some cases this could be the reason of OS reboot ?

Comment: This might happen, but in this case I would consider this very unlikely.  There is most likely another cause for this problem.

Comment: ok , this machine is datenode machine ( worker )  which have HDFS file-system on the disks ( part of hadoop cluster ) , I not sure if we need this service , but maybe hortonworks know the answer , if you can put light on that I will hapy to get remark

Comment: These commands are deprecated and should not be used on current Linux systems. You will need to use `systemctl` instead.